# Objective-C, border color not working with UIColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I can set the border color using the following code:

```
[[self.single layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:178.0f/255.0f green:178.0f/255.0f blue:178.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] CGColor];
```

and it works just fine.  But I need to apply this to multiple borders, so I tried the following:

.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIColor *appColor;
```

.m

within `viewDidLoad`

```
self.appColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:178.0f/255.0f green:178.0f/255.0f blue:178.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
```

and then later, where the previous color assignment was

```
[[self.single layer] setBorderColor:[self.appColor CGColor]];
```

But this does not work - the border comes out black (regardless of what I set for `self.appColor`).  I have also tried `[[self.single layer] setBorderColor:self.appColor.CGColor];` with no success.  How can I define a UIColor variable just once, but use it to assign border colors in multiple places?

Comment: check `self.appColor` is not `nil`?

Comment: Yes, in particular, making `appColor` a weak property is suspicious.

Comment: @JesseRusak Yep, that did it.  Changed it to strong and it's working fine.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: the reason makes self.appColor = nil is you use an weak property. [UIColor colorWithRed:Green:Blue:Alpha] will create an autorealease object. You assign it to weak property. After run loop, the UIColor will release and weak property automatically assign to nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIColor *appColor;
```

To:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *appColor;
```

And see if this helps you.

Comment: Its ok, i dislike notifications anyways